# How are OpenCL work-group scheduled on Intel FPGA?

Tags: opencl, fpga

I have a question about work-group scheduling on multiple CUs in Intel FPGA. As work-groups are assigned to available CUs, when is a CU considered available? Is it when the last work-item of the previous work-group has abandoned​ the pipeline or when it is at its second stage (so every stage of the pipeline is occupied by the previous work-group except the first one)? This decision is taken by the hardware scheduler, but I haven't found any public documentation explaining any of this.

Edit: I'm talking about the automatic process that takes place when using Intel OpenCL SDK for FPGA, not a custom design with HDL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from work-items, work-groups are also pipelined in each CU. Hence, you have multiple work-groups in-flight in the same CU at the same time, to maximize pipeline efficiency. If your design uses local-memory-based buffers, when you check the HTML report, you will see that the compiler is further replicating those buffers to support a specific number of "Simultaneous Work-groups". The number of such work-groups seems to be equal to pipeline depth per CU divided by work-group size. In the end, all work-item from all work-groups running simultaneously in the same CU are pipelined one after another, with work-items belonging to each CU using their own local buffers, and barrier synchronization being enforced per work-group. A new work-group will be scheduled in each CU, probably after one of the simultaneously-running work-groups has completely left the CU.

P.S. It is probably easier to get help related to Intel FPGA SDK for OpenCL in their own forum.

P.P.S. The details of Intel's OpenCL work-item scheduler is not documented anywhere.